# PHP Forms - Which input is incorrect?

Tags: php, forms, error-handling

If I have a query,

```
SELECT (...) FROM User WHERE Username = (...) AND Password = (...);
```

and the user types in an invalid Username is there a way to pick up that it was specifically the Username that was incorrect?

This is so that I can give more specific error messages to the user, like "User does not exist" etc...

Comment: this is a bad idea for security reasons. if you say the user exists, then they have a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Don't do that.  If you tell the user specifically that the username doesn't exist, you open yourself to brute force attacks.

Comment: That's probably a bad idea. Once a malicious user locks onto a "valid username, invalid password", you've done half the work for them.

Comment: I had thought about that, thanks

Comment: Really don't do that, its a huge security flaw. Don't do their work for them!

Comment: All should note that our advice should be simply not to show the user this info. However, it is still highly valuable to determine in code; for instance to email a user a notice if there are x number of failed attempts with their account. (or else to lock out the user, or log the attempts. It can be valuable insight to know that the user was trying different usernames or same username different passwords)

Comment: Also, we should make the obligatory "please accept more answers" comment. 2 of 13 is not helping your cause :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `User` WHERE `Username` = ...;

if( $result['count'] < 1 )
{
  // no user
}

// repeat for pass.
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it would be achieved, but as said its a bad idea for security reasons.

Comment: @j5Dev: Whilst I don't disagree, it is still a correct solution to the posed question.

Answer (score 0):

I would select the username and then a bit-field on if the password matched. So remove the password part from the WHERE clause, and move it into the SELECT clause. Then, no matching rows means invalid username, and if you have a row, you need to check that field to see if the password matches.

```
SELECT (...) IF(password=?, 1, 0) as success
FROM User
WHERE Username = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're **adamant** about doing it this way, you can do:

```
SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?
```

If there's no record found, the username doesn't exist.  If it does, you can now compare the password.